# yii\grid\ActionColumn only visible for logged in users in Yii2

Tags: yii2

How can the `yii\grid\ActionColumn` of `GridView::widget` made visible only for loggged in users ?
My code in view is

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'state_id',
            'state_name',
            'population',
            'state_code',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yii\grid\ActionColumn` class is inherited from `yii\grid\Column` class. The latter has [visible](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail) property. You can use it with condition that returns boolean value.

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
],
```